# Evaluate The Arc Length

Tags: integration, differential-geometry

> Let $$\alpha(t)=(\alpha \cos^3t,\alpha \sin^3 t)$$ Evaluate the arc length when $\alpha>0$ and $t\in[0,2\pi]$

$$\alpha'(t)=(-3\alpha \cos^2{t} \sin{t} ,3\alpha \sin^2t\ \cos t)$$

$$||\alpha'(t)||=\sqrt{(-3\alpha \cos^2{t} \sin{t})^2+(3\alpha \sin^2t\ \cos t)^2}=\sqrt{9\alpha^2\cos^4{t} \sin^2{t}+9\alpha^2 \sin^4t\ cos^2t}=\sqrt{9\alpha^2\cos^2t\sin^2t(\cos^2t+\sin^2t)}=\sqrt{9\alpha^2\cos^4{t} \sin^2{t}+9\alpha^2 \sin^4t\cos^2t}=\sqrt{9\alpha^2\cos^2t\sin^2t}=3\alpha \cos t \sin t$$

So we have:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}||\alpha'(t)||dt=\int_{0}^{2\pi}(3\alpha \cos t  \sin t)\,dt=3\alpha \int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos t \sin t\, dt$$

$u=\sin t$ and $du=\cos t\, dt$

$$3\alpha \int_{0}^{2\pi} udu=3\alpha\frac{u^2}{2}|_{0}^{2\pi}=\frac{3}{2}\alpha{\sin t^2}|_{0}^{2\pi}=\frac{3}{2}(0-0)=0$$

But the answer is $6\alpha$ where did I get it wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that ou want $\alpha$ in lhs and rhs ? It looks confusing. Otherwise, integrate from $0$ to $\frac \pi 2$ and multiply the result by $4$.

Comment: $$\sqrt{9\alpha^2\cos^2t\sin^2t}=3\alpha |\cos t \sin t|$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici why from 0 to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and not 0 to $\pi$ where sin function is positive too?

Comment: @gbox. Because of the symmetry.

Comment: Your error occurs where you say $\sqrt{9\alpha^2\cos^2t\sin^2t}=3\alpha \cos t \sin t$. It should be $\sqrt{9\alpha^2\cos^2t\sin^2t}=3\alpha| \cos t \sin t|$. See my solution below for another way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The curve you have given has both negative and positive parts in that domain of $t$.  So these cancel out giving you zero when you integrate it the way you have done so above.  I would restrict the bounds to only calculate the arc length in each quadrant then add them.  This is because when $t\in[0,2\pi]$, $\alpha (t)$ is in all $4$ quadrants.  Integrate it from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, this will give you only the length of the curve when both $x$ and $y$ are positive, then you move to the next quadrant and add these values.  However, since this curve involves sines and cosines, you can simply multiply it by $4$ as you know the same value will be obtained in each domain.

Comment: Why for example cant we look at $[0,\pi]$ and $[\pi,2\pi]$ (where sin is negative)

Comment: I am saying that you have to look at all of these domains and add them all together.

Answer (score 1):

Here another way to do this, this time in the complex plane. Let the astroid be given by

$$z=a(\cos^2 t+i~b\sin^3 t),\quad t\in[0,2\pi]$$

The arc length is given by

$$
\begin{align}
s
&=\int_0^{2\pi}|\dot z|~dt\\
&=4\int_0^{\pi/2}|\dot z|~dt,\quad \text{by symmetry}\\
&=4a\int_0^{\pi/2}|-3\cos^2 t~\sin t+3\sin^2 t~\cos t|~dt\\
&=4a\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{9\cos^4 t~\sin^2 t+9\sin^4 t~\cos^2 t}~dt\\
&=4a\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\cos^2 t~\sin^2 t}~dt\\
&=12a\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin t~d(\sin t)\\
&=6a \sin^2 t\biggr|_0^{\pi/2}\\
&=6a
\end{align}
$$